# Error de conexión entre SQL Developer y Oracle

Tags: oracle-sqldeveloper

Soy estudiante de un curso sobre BBDD y he instalado en mi PC el SQL Developer y la versión gratuita de Oracle para poder hacer mis prácticas en casa.
El caso es que llevo 50 días encerrado en casa y no consigo contactar con mi profesor para resolver este problema:
Al tratar de conectar ambas herramientas se produce el error:

```
 ERROR: ORA 12505 TNS:listener does not currently kwon of SID...
```

Agradecería inmensamente instrucciones de un buen samaritano para poder establecer la conexión y avanzar. En un "español", por favor!!!!! No soy informático.
Gracias anticipadas

Comment: En la conexión de sql developer en algun lado dice avanzado. Ahi podes ingresar la url de conexión jdbc. Tiene este formato: jdbc:oracle:thin:@hostname:port Number:databaseName. Si todo está en la mimsma maquina, hostname es 127.0.0.1

Comment: No consigo resolverlo, pero muchas gracias por tu respuesta Jbeltrán